# calculate number of qualified opportunities?

Tags: opportunity

Want to count Number of Qualified Opportunities

where

Qualified Opportunities = count of qualified opportunities for which opportunity (“StageName = Closed Won” and “StageName = Closed Lost”)

Comment: Do you need to write a SOQL?

Comment: Where do you need to see this information ? Into Account ? Report? Can you provide a bit more information ?

Comment: Nishant you need to provide some more context around where you're trying to do this, and why you're stuck.

Comment: @LaceyShr Solved my query with JimRae's comment. Had to do with apex where isClosed=True worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do this in a report, and you use the Opportunity Report type, you can select the "Opportunity Status" filter of "Closed". This is better than using stagename ="Closed Lost" "Closed Won" because it is possible to have other stagename's that are also defined as Closed.

If you are doing this with Apex, you could, as @Birthus suggested, do an opportunity SOQL query, although again, I would suggest that you use the `isClosed ='True'` filter.

```
Integer numberOfOpp = [SELECT Id 
                       FROM Opportunity 
                       WHERE isClosed=true].size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use

```
(“StageName = Closed Won” and “StageName = Closed Lost”)
```

Because that can't ever happend! StageName is picklist and can have only one value at time
Try

```
Integer numberOfOpp = [SELECT Id 
                       FROM Opportunity 
                       WHERE StageName = 'Closed Won' OR StageName = 'Closed Lost'].size();
```

You could also use report to count them